# Is there any way to save my virtual box contents,? I want to change my host operating system from ubuntu to Kali

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, kali-linux

Currently I am running Ubuntu 16.04. However I want to change to Kali Linux as it will be more efficient for my lab projects. Is there any way to save my virtual machines that I am running in Oracle's VirtualBox?

Comment: Do you not have an external USB drive? Or go old school and use a DVD-R...

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your VirtualBox are stored in files called disk images. You can backup these disk images on some external media, and move them back after you're done. This will let you keep all your virtual machines' data.

These disk images are typically located in the .VirtualBox hidden folder in your home directory. Simply copy these somewhere that isn't being reformatted, and readd them to VirtualBox after reinstalling. Check your VM's settings for the full location if you can't find it.